# Css accordion menu, how to set height to automatic?

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

I've got this accordion menu:
[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dcvgy)

The problem is that the height of the expanding divs is "hardcoded" (see where the css comment is), whereas I need it to expand according to the number of submenu items.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `height: auto`

```
#accordion div:hover {
    height:auto; /* THIS NEEDS TO ADJUST AUTOMATICALLY */
}
```

Comment: This works, however, it breaks the transition effect :/

Comment: Fixes the transition by using max-height instead.